# Non-blocking alternative to Object.wait()?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, coroutine

I have one thread receiving packets from a local server:

```
// Shared object:
@Volatile lateinit var recentPacket: Packet
val recvMutex = Object()

// Thread code:
thread(isDaemon = true) {
    while (true) {
        val packet = readPacket()
        synchronized(recvMutex) {
            recentPacket = packet
            recvMutex.notifyAll()
        }
    }
}
```

And I have **multiple** other threads waiting for packets, each of which should get the same packet that was just received:

```
suspend fun receive() {
    return synchronized(recvMutex) {
        recvMutex.wait() // non-blocking alternative to this?
        recentPacket
    }
}
```

It works, but `Object.wait()` blocks the thread. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: The whole point to wait() is to block. It would help to describe what you are trying to do with the wait() call. From what I understand, you want one producer thread to notify n consumer threads of the same packet received? Or is it that you want n threads to pull off one queue where each task on the queue is eventually only executed by a single thread?

Comment: @Charlie: I want 1 producer thread to notify n consumer threads of the same packet. I want some way to _suspend the coroutine_ (not block) until another packet arrives (sorry I wasn't clear).

Comment: I can only describe it from the Java world, but you're using Object.wait incorrectly. The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) (and presumably the KDoc) describes how you should use it - you need to check a condition (for example, the recent packet is not null and not the same as they one that you've already seen) and only when that condition isn't met, you should wait (in a `while` loop), and check again after the `wait` whether the condition is now satisfied.

Comment: @StephenC The caller of `receive()` is a coroutine.

Comment: And what exactly will those other threads be doing before they receive the item? Do they run event loops?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: [Kotlin handles it:](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines-basic-jvm.html) "The thread is returned to the pool while the coroutine is waiting, and when the waiting is done, the coroutine resumes on a free thread in the pool."

Comment: @null That depends on the coroutine context used, but you didn't specifiy it. Are you using `CommonPool`? If yes, then you should redesign and replace `wait-notify` with channels.

Comment: Coroutines have nothing to do with wait. They are different synchronization primitives.

Comment: Actually, thread pools are a third kind of synchronization/parallelism but I don't know how they interact with coroutines.

Comment: @charlie Coroutines are not synchronization primitives. Thread pools are not a kind of synchronization, either.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Agreed; that's why I used a slash with parallelism =)

Comment: Your code is currently broken because the mutex isn't protecting anything. Fix the code so we can see what the mutex protects and then you'll have an answerable question. (If it protects `recentPacket`, then just check `recentPacket` instead of calling `wait`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It works, but `Object.wait()` blocks the thread. Is there a way to avoid this?

Yes, but it means removing the complete `wait-notify` idiom you use now and replacing it with Kotlin's native `BroadcastChannel`.

Here is a basic example with two receivers and five packets being broadcast:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.asCoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.BroadcastChannel
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.SubscriptionReceiveChannel
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.runBlocking
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

private val threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool() as ExecutorService
val MyPool = threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val packetChannel = BroadcastChannel<Packet>(1)
    (1..2).forEach {
        launch(MyPool) {
            receivePackets(it, packetChannel.openSubscription())
        }
    }
    runBlocking {
        (1..5).forEach {
            packetChannel.send(Packet(it))
            delay(100)
        }
    }
    threadPool.shutdown()
}

suspend fun receivePackets(index: Int, packetChannel: SubscriptionReceiveChannel<Packet>) {
    while (true) {
        println("Receiver $index got packet ${packetChannel.receive().value}")
    }
}

data class Packet(
        val value: Int
)
```

Expect to see output such as this:

```
Receiver 1 got packet 1
Receiver 2 got packet 1
Receiver 2 got packet 2
Receiver 1 got packet 2
Receiver 1 got packet 3
Receiver 2 got packet 3
Receiver 1 got packet 4
Receiver 2 got packet 4
Receiver 1 got packet 5
Receiver 2 got packet 5
```

Answer (score -1):

Coroutines seem to be in an experimental state; I suggest waiting until those mature before using them. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html#experimental-status-of-coroutines

I the mean time, you might try a `ThreadPool`:

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket
import java.net.DatagramSocket
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import kotlin.concurrent.thread

fun start() {
    val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)
    thread(isDaemon = true) {
        val socket = DatagramSocket(12345)
        while (!socket.isClosed) {
            val packet = DatagramPacket(ByteArray(1000), 0)
            socket.receive(packet)
            pool.submit({
                receive(packet)
            })
        }
    }
    pool.shutdown()
}

fun receive(packet: DatagramPacket) {
    println(String(packet.data, 0, packet.length))
}
```

Asynchronous IO might be useful; You can look into [Java Selectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html)

Comment: Coroutines are already quite mature and production-ready, and I can attest to that from my personal experience. The only reason why they are still experimental is that the team hasn't yet settled on every detail of API design. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46240340/1103872