# handler.postDelayed from within runnable shows syntax error in Kotlin - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, task, handler, runnable

```
private val progressTask = Runnable {
    runOnUiThread { if (!tvMessage.text.isEmpty()) tvMessage.text = "" }
    pbLoading.progress++
    when {
        pbLoading.progress == 600 -> finalFunction()
        pbLoading.progress % 20 == 0 -> runOnUiThread {
            tvMessage.text = messages[pbLoading.progress / 20]
        }
    }
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
}
```

This code is giving me an syntax error under the `this` keyword. Saying that this error points to my activity rather than the runnable itself. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can’t do this with a regular lambda. In order to make `this` refer to the `Runnable`, use the `object` syntax:

```
val runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        println("$this runs in a runnable")
    }
}
```

It’s slightly more verbose and that’s the price you pay.

Answer (score 2):

Let me offer you a deeper solution to your problem: do yourself a favor and switch to Kotlin coroutines. This is how your code would look with them:

```
fun showLoadingProgress(tvMessage: TextView, pbLoading: ProgressBar) = launch(UI) {
    if (!tvMessage.text.isEmpty()) tvMessage.text = ""
    with(pbLoading) {
        do {
            delay(1000)
            if (progress++ % 20 == 0) tvMessage.text = messages[progress / 20]
        } while (progress < 600)
        finalFunction()
    }
}
```

If you're worried that they are still "experimental", that just means their API is still not finalized. JetBrains has already [committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240236/can-experimental-kotlin-coroutines-be-used-in-production) to maintain backwards compatibility with the experimental API and I can personally attest to the robustness of its implementation — I have never experienced any issues at all with it.

---

You mentioned your concern that you also have to pause your progress monitor and then resume it at a later time. With coroutines you'd achieve it as follows:

1. Within `showLoadingProgress()` you'll write

   ```
   suspendCoroutine { cont -> this.progressMonitorContinuation = cont }
   ```

   This implies the existence of a `var progressMonitorContinuation: Continuation<Unit>?`.
2. When you're ready to resume the progress monitor, write

   ```
   val cont = this.progressMonitorContinuation!!
   this.progressMonitorContinuation = null
   launch(UI) { cont.resume(Unit) }
   ```

Comment: Interesting. But I am also pausing the task midway and starting it again. I can currently do this with Handlers, but don't know how to with this.

Comment: thumbs up for awesome solution :)

Answer (score 1):

> This code is giving me an syntax error under the this keyword

At first, modify your [**`runOnUiThread`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) method in Kotlin

```
private val progressTask = Runnable {
        activity!!.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
            Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {

                // YOUR CODE

            }, 1000)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you used in kotlin handler like below code

```
 private val progressTask = Runnable {
        runOnUiThread { if (!tvMessage.text.isEmpty()) tvMessage.text = "" }
        pbLoading.progress++
        when {
            pbLoading.progress == 600 -> finalFunction()
            pbLoading.progress % 20 == 0 -> runOnUiThread {
                tvMessage.text = messages[pbLoading.progress / 20]
            }
        }
        Handler().postDelayed(this, 1000)
    }
```

if passing this keyword then run() method implement.

```
  override fun run() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

//Create handler instance

```
private val handler = Handler()

private val progressTask = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        println("$this runs in a runnable")

        runOnUiThread { if (!tvMessage.text.isEmpty()) tvMessage.text = "" }
        pbLoading.progress++
        when {
            pbLoading.progress == 600 -> finalFunction()
            pbLoading.progress % 20 == 0 -> runOnUiThread {
                tvMessage.text = messages[pbLoading.progress / 20]
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
    }
}
```